# How to Load Different Javascript Files Based on Input

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm working on a map that will allow the user to select one of two expressions of a dataset and toggle between them. Each expressions is set up in its own .js (main_heat.js for a heatmap, main.js for proportional symbols).

My issue is setting up controls in my index.html file that will and load the selected expression based on a click. The following code doesn't throw errors, but doesn't produce the result (reloading a different expression) that I am expecting:

index.html:

```
<div id ="expression">
    <h4>Choose your expression</h4>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('heat');">Heatmap</a> |
    <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('prop');">Proportional Symbols</a>
</div>
<!--EXTERNAL SCRIPT LINKS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_heat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
function changeExpression(src){
    var heat = document.createElement("script");
        heat.src = "js/main_heat.js";
        document.body.appendChild(heat);
    var prop = document.createElement("script");
        prop.src = "js/main.js";
        document.body.appendChild(prop);

    if (src === "heat"){
        loadScript("main_heat.js")
    } else if (src === "prop"){
        loadScript("main.js");
    }
};

function loadScript(src){
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Both `changeExpression` and `loadScript` are called in an initial callback function in main.js, and I'm struggling to see why the "onclick" in index.html doesn't produce a change. Does anybody see where I'm going wrong or have an insight on what might be causing this?

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Why is `changeExpression()` loading both files itself and then also calling `loadScript()` to load just one of them? Why do you have the `js/` directory in one case?

Comment: Checking the console... it looks like when I load the page, and when I click the two options, there are errors saying "Map container is already initialized." Good catch with the ```js/``` directory, that had been an oversight.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the code for the two expressions. They both try to create an object, and the code that creates it is designed to be run only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can achieve what you want if you need to run different scripts based on 'onClick'.

1. If the size of Js files does not matter best way is to add Js files with script tags in the 'index.html' file as below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id ="expression">
      <h4>Choose your expression</h4>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('heat');">Heatmap</a> |
      <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('prop');">Proportional Symbols</a>
  </div>
</body>

<!--EXTERNAL SCRIPT LINKS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_heat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

2. In case you need to add those two scripts based on onClick, You can do it with a simple function as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id ="expression">
      <h4>Choose your expression</h4>
      <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('heat');">Heatmap</a> |
      <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('prop');">Proportional Symbols</a>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let changeExpression = function (type) {
    let elem = document.createElement("script");
    
    if (type === 'heat') {
      elem.src = "js/main_heat.js";
    } else {
      elem.src = "js/main.js";
    }
    map.off();
    map.remove();
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second solution worked! Thank you! Just had to add ```map.off()``` and ```map.remove()``` to get everything to show up.

Comment: Great! Welcome. Is it required any map.off() or map.remove() in my answer? If so please correct.

Answer (score 0):

- Missing a semi-colon at end of line `loadScript("main_heat.js")`
- Check the paths to your scripts because they're different (in one place you omit the directory) and therefore are likely not found
- Check the console for any error like `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
- Consider adding code to check if script is already appended because every click will append it again